# Route NTP traffic through Routing-Instance

Tags: routing, juniper-ex, ntp

Switch 2 needs to route it's NTP requests through a specific vlan that is setup on a routing-instance.

Current NTP setup on switch 2 is

```
set system ntp server 10.0.0.21
set system ntp source-address 10.0.6.15 routing-instance MGMT-6
```

Routing-instance is setup as follows:

```
set routing-instances MGMT-6 description "Policy for MGMT network routing"
set routing-instances MGMT-6 instance-type virtual-router
set routing-instances MGMT-6 interface vlan.6
set routing-instances MGMT-6 routing-options static route 10.0.0.0/23 next-hop 10.0.6.1
set routing-instances MGMT-6 routing-options static route 10.0.6.0/24 next-hop 10.0.6.1
set routing-instances MGMT-6 routing-options static route 10.100.4.0/23 next-hop 10.0.6.1
```

[image]

I've seen different suggestions, including

```
set forwarding-options helpers port 123 server 127.0.0.1
set forwarding-options helpers port 123 server routing-instance MGMT-6
```

But it has no effect. Any suggestions?

Comment: We may need to see more of your configuration off of switch 1 to know what is going on. Specifically, do you have only one routing-instance or multiple? Details of exactly what ties to each routing instance, etc.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you have a misconfiguration in one of your static routes with the next-hop clause.

Where you configuration shows this:

```
set routing-instances MGMT-6 routing-options static route 10.0.0.0/23 next-hop 10.0.6.1
```

It should instead read this:

```
set routing-instances MGMT-6 routing-options static route 10.0.0.0/23 next-hop 10.0.0.1
```

**Edit:** been a while since I worked on a Juniper device, so now having doubts. We may need to see more of the configuration to know exactly which changes are required to allow this.

Comment: If you set it that way, the routing-instance wouldn't know how to find 10.0.0.1. Right now, I can connect through ssh to it, so it seems to be able to route correctly, it's just not using NTP through that instance. What additional information would you like?

Comment: I misread your original question and thought you were providing the routing instance from switch 1. We would need to see configuration from switch 1 as well to answer this as it appears that is the switch that doing the actual routing. There may be some sort of ACL/security in place on one of the two switches (often the device providing routing) that needs to be adjusted.

Comment: Thanks, switch 2 is relatively flat. I was trying to segregate the management vlan out. The two other vlans are not L3 interfaces. I changed the routing table and put the routing-instances into routing-options and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the before comment is rigth. You have two vlans, with two vlan interfaces, to do routing in your swicht, you should send the next hope to your vlan interfaces in the network that you have the destination

set routing-instances MGMT-6 routing-options static route 10.0.0.0/23 next-hop 10.0.0.1

Because 10.0.0.1, seems to be the ip address of your vlan interfaces of your VLAN DATA

Comment: Wouldn't Switch 2 would be unaware of how to find the 10.0.0.1 or 10.0.0.0/23?

Comment: Then friend, on this way, you are rigth, but, then, you must set the gateway on your server, pointing to 10.0.0.1, or, if you have one, set an static route, with destination 10.0.6.0 pointing  to 10.0.0.1. On this way, the answer will have a route to arrive to Switch 2.